# Why can't I run this MongoDB query in Node, but it works in community compass?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to run this MongoDB query from my Node app, I am trying to query a specific date.

So far I have tried this:

```
    x = await dbo.collection("master").find({Process: "Process1"}).toArray();

    x = x.map(o => o.Finish_Time);

    xtime= recent_time(x) //function finds the maximum time in an array

    console.log(xtime) //returns '2019-06-12T08:05:33.000Z'

    query_result = await dbo.collection("master").find({Finish_Time: xtime}).map(o => o.Shortnum);
```

In short, all this query does is pull all dates for `Process1`, uses `recent_time()` function to find the most recent date. The most recent date is then used to find the full document for that process.

The document in my MongoDB looks like this:

```
{"_id":"<key_id_here>",
"Process":"Process1",
"Shortnum":"002494",
"Status":1,
"Start_Time":"2019-06-12T07:53:22.000Z",
"Finish_Time":"2019-06-12T08:05:33.000Z"}
```

My query should return `Shortnum` however it returns nothing. I also find it strange that if I query this in the Compass app using `{Finish_Time: '2019-06-12T08:05:33.000Z'}` it returns the correct document. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could it be a problem comparing date objects with strings? I mean that if in database you have stored a string but `xtime` is a date object (although when making `console.log(xtime)` look like a string) it wouldn't match and maybe you should do `.find({Finish_Time: xtime.toISOString()})`.

Comment: What is the type of `xtime` and what is the type of `Finish_Time` field in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

```
x = await dbo.collection("master").find({Process: "Process1"}).toArray();
```

If this line don't return anything, the problem would by with de "Process", can you try to change to this, or show the return in a console.log?

```
x = await dbo.collection("master").find({"Process": "Process1"}).toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response however I don't think this is correct, everything works up to the point of `query_result`

Comment: @EcSync your question indicates that you are not getting correct results in `x` and in comment you are saying that it works correct until `query_result` ?

Comment: @Arun No it doesn't, it indicates that `xtime` returns the correct time, however when running the query through my code with `xtime` it doesn't work. Where as it does work in Compass - so `x` and `xtime` must be correct